# How to grant only functions while revoking tables?

Tags: postgresql, permissions

I am a newbie to PostgreSQL, and configuring a new database.

I wrote several functions for indirect access(read/write) to data, and I want to prohibit all direct access to table.

```
GRANT CONNECT ON DATABASE db1 TO role1;
GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA schema1 TO role1;

REVOKE ALL ON table1 FROM role1;
GRANT ALL ON ALL FUNCTIONS IN SCHEMA schema1 TO role1;
```

If I don't REVOKE table privilege, direct table access will be allowed. If I REVOKE table privilege, and GRANT functions, Users access the functions but see table access restriction error.

```
psql:./test1.psql:6: ERROR:  permission denied for relation table1
```

How can I make user `role1` can access data using only functions while disallowing all direct access to table? I think I missed something, but I can't figure it out.

P.S. I am using Postgres 9.2.x.

Comment: It's always best to mention your PostgreSQL versions in questions, btw.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want to make your functions `SECURITY DEFINER` and have them owned by a user that *does* have the requisite rights.

Be very careful when coding `SECURITY DEFINER` functions. Don't make them owned by a superuser and read the manual carefully. Create a role that has only the rights required and no more; give it ownership of the `SECURITY DEFINER` functions. Where appropriate create multiple roles for different access levels.

See [`CREATE FUNCTION`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createfunction.html).

Comment: Nice answer Craig! So, in this case, the owner of the functions will only have rights to read and wirte on the affected tables?